# PHP как FastCGI

Tags: php, настройки

> За счет кэширования некоторых промежуточных данных скрипт не
>   интерпретируется каждый раз при выполнении и достигается более высокая
>   скорость по сравнению с PHP как CGI.

Вопрос: Как отключить это кэширование?
Пояснения: Это мне мешает работать над скриптом, изменяю его много много раз в минуту. И хочу видеть результат сразу после изменения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `FastCGI` в файле конфигурации виртуальных хостов `nginx` или `fastcgi.conf`

```
fastcgi_cache  off;
```